# gitlab-runner ERROR: Preparation failed: VBoxManageOutput error: VBoxManage: error: Could not find a registered machine named

Tags: gitlab, vagrant, virtualbox, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I want to use gitlab-runner virtualbox executor with just simple debian box so my **vagrant file** is

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
 config.vm.box = "debian/buster64"
end
```

**First approach**

1. `vagrant up`
2. change name: settings->general->name "my-vm"
3. shut down vm
4. `sudo gitlab-runner register` ...some manual commands...
5. `sudo gitlab-runner install --user $(whoami)`
6. `sudo gitlab-runner start`

I can see my runner in my Gitlab Settings CI. It's green. Then I run my job and I get the following problem: `ERROR: Preparation failed: VBoxManageOutput error: VBoxManage: error: Could not find a registered machine named my-vm` **but** in my console

```
VBoxManage list vms
"my-vm" {aaf0b3ff-3c5b-4324-9b2f-034d26036278}
```

**Second approach (from scratch)**

1. `vagrant up`
2. change name: settings->general->name "my-vm"
3. shut down vm
4. `gitlab-runner register` ...some manual commands...

   ```
   WARNING: Running in user-mode.                     
   WARNING: The user-mode requires you to manually start builds processing: 
   WARNING: $ gitlab-runner run                       
   WARNING: Use sudo for system-mode:                 
   WARNING: $ sudo gitlab-runner...
   ```
5. `sudo gitlab-runner install --user $(whoami)`
6. `sudo gitlab-runner start`
7. `gitlab-runner run`

**The Second approach** fixed the problem: my runner can see the box and everything works as expected but new one appear:

I don't want to execute `gitlab-runner run` every time when I want to run jobs. I prefer the **first approach** but I get the problem when my runner cant find box.

I can use `sudo vagrant up` and then change name via **sudo** VBoxManage  way and it will work but it looks like more as a workaround.

I can't find any example or explanation how I can solve my issue. How people do this in a area of good practices?